# Start activity for NFC tags reading Android 2.3

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, nfc

As I understand, the Android 2.3 uses a single step approach for NFC tag detection (`TAG_DISCOVERED` only).

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
```

This means that if more then one activity declares the intent to read NFC tag, the activity selection dialog “*Complete action using*” pop-ups because the “*Tags*” application already has an `TagViewer` activity for handling the NFC tags.

Is there a way to avoid the dialog?

BR
STeN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're out of luck in stock 2.3; you'll get that dialog as long as the default Tags app is also installed.

However, in the 2.3.3 update and later, there's a more complicated set of intent-filters.  See here:
http://programming-android.labs.oreilly.com/ch16.html#ch18_id316624

You may be able to use the ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED filter to catch it before the tags app does with the normal TAG_DISCOVERED fitler. A downside is that you might need to register for certain URIs or MIME types.  I haven't tried this myself.

Comment: I also think this is not possible - but anyway it is always better to ask then rely only on own...

Answer (score 0):

The best way is enableForegroundDispatch() function.